# Dynamically determine the IntStream.range()

Tags: java, java-stream, range, bufferedreader, intstream

I hve this code which loops through lines of integers and enters them into a `List`:

```
BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

List<List<Integer>> arr = new ArrayList<>();


IntStream.range(0, 12).forEach(i -> {
    try {
        arr.add(
                Stream.of(bufferedReader.readLine().replaceAll("\\s+$", "").split(" "))
                        .map(Integer::parseInt)
                        .collect(toList())
        );
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        throw new RuntimeException(ex);
    }
});
```

It works fine when I pass in the correct number of rows. 12 in this example. I'd like to make this dynamic so various numbers of rows could be entered. How is this done?

Comment: Just use a `while` loop. Not everything has to be streams.

Comment: Or use `bufferedReader.lines()`, which returns a `Stream<String>`, and then use the stream API to collect into a `List<List<Integer>>`. But a `while` loop would probably be more readable.

Answer (score 1):

> I'd like to make this dynamic so various numbers of rows could be entered. How is this done?

There's a couple of way to avoid hard-coding the number of lines that should be read from the console:

- you can provide the expected number of lines (for instance as a method argument, or as a console input);
- introduce a condition checking where a particular string (or symbol) which should signify the end of data is present in the input.

As *@Slaw* has mentioned in the [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74379666/dynamically-determine-the-intstream-range#comment131308206_74379666), you can use [`BufferedReader.lines()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/io/BufferedReader.html#lines()) which generates a stream lazily populated with lines read from the `BufferedReader`.

Also, note that instead of `replaceAll("\\s+$", "")` which is intended to remove white trailing spaces, you can apply [`String.strip()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#strip()) (or its predecessor `trim()`).

## Provide a number of lines explicitly

The first option is to provide the number of rows to read explicitly and apply it via `limit()` operation.

```
public static List<List<Integer>> readInput(int limit) {
    var reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    
    return reader.lines()
        .map(line -> Arrays.stream(line.strip().split(" "))
            .map(Integer::parseInt)
            .toList()
        )
        .limit(limit) // number of lines to read
        .toList();    // collect(toList())
}
```

## Read until a specific condition is met

Another approach is to read the data until input a string representing the end of data is not encountered in the input. Since regular data in these case contains only digits and white spaces, we can make it terminating condition, i.e. read until input is valid.

```
public static List<List<Integer>> readInput() {
    var reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    
    return reader.lines()
        .takeWhile(line -> line.matches("\\d+[\\s\\d]*")) // read until there only digits in the input
        .map(line -> Arrays.stream(line.strip().split(" "))
            .map(Integer::parseInt)
            .toList()
        )
        .toList();   // collect(toList())
}
```